# Multipeer Connectivity session from Connecting to NotConnected

Tags: ios, swift, macos, multipeer-connectivity

I developed a very simple concept project to test Multipeer Connectivity framework on both OS X and iOS platform. They could find each other every time, but cannot be connected. The session state will be changed from Connecting to NotConnected.

I have tried on different MacBook and iOS device, also on iOS simulators, and the same behavior.

My source code has been uploaded to https://gist.github.com/hcwang/1a62d7a2def4d271d950.

Thanks for your kindly help.

Answer (score -1):

I believe in your function

```
func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveCertificate certificate: [AnyObject]?, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, certificateHandler: (Bool) -> Void){

}
```

you need ...

```
func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceiveCertificate certificate: [Any]?, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, certificateHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    certificateHandler(true)
}
```

Hope that helps